# How can I move Files between folders when the phone is connected to the desktop

Tags: file-transfer, sd-card, organization

I wanted to reorganize some photos on my SDCard. I mounted the phone, opened two explorer windows with source and destination folder and tried to move the selected files from source to destination. Unfortunaley they only get copied even when the explorer showed the "move to" context menu command. I tried also using the TotalCommander MTP plugin, but here the "move" command also give an error.

Is there an option to move files without taking the SDCArd out of the phone and mount it directly to the pc?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK moving files is not supported as your phone is just recognized as a flash drive, but it actually isn't one - this function is just "emulated". You can "move" files on your SD Card either

- by copying the files to the new destination and then deleting the source files. If you run into space problems you could copy the files to your PC first, then delete them on the phone and finally synch them back to the new location.
- by plugging the SD Card into a card reader and moving it from there
- or by using a file manager app on the phone (like the official [files app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e))

Comment: Yes, I know that the MTP protocol doesn't expose the filesystem. But I could think of a desktop explorer app which would emulate this by copying and deleting the file from its orignal place afterwards. Meanwhile I did directly edit the SDCard, which is by far the fastest solution.

Comment: Is this possible? I wasn't sure about how WP formats the card. Unfortunately I don't know of such an app.

Comment: On my AtivS with WP8.1 it was no problem. It's even no problem moving a previously used SDCArd from Android to WPhone without loosing the stored images. I just adjusted it to the folder structure. I suppose, only the OS internal state files are encrypted.

Comment: good to know, good to know... ty.